# Use uasort to sort elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
$array = array(
        'note' => array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),
        'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012', '2009', '2010'),
        'type' => array('journal', 'conference', 'conference', 'conference','conference'),
    );
```

And I would like to sort the elements using `uasort()` and array `year`.

I did:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   if($a['year'] == $b['year']) return 0;
   return ($a['year'] < $b['year']) ? -1 : 1;
} 

uasort($array,'cmp');

print_r($array);
```

But the output is incorrect:

```
Array
(
[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => journal
        [1] => conference
        [2] => conference
        [3] => conference
        [4] => conference
    )

[year] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2011
        [1] => 2010
        [2] => 2012
        [3] => 2009
        [4] => 2010
    )

[note] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => test1
        [2] => test2
        [3] => test3
        [4] => test4
    )

)
```

Desired output:

```
Array
(
[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => conference
        [1] => journal
        [2] => conference
        [3] => conference
        [4] => conference
    )

[year] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2012
        [1] => 2011
        [2] => 2010
        [3] => 2010
        [4] => 2009
    )

[note] => Array
    (
        [0] => test2
        [1] => test
        [2] => test1
        [3] => test4
        [4] => test3
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input seems wrong. Try something like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'note' => 'test',
        'year' => 2011,
        'type' => 'journal',
    ),
    array(
        'note' => 'test1',
        'year' => 2010,
        'type' => 'conference',
    ),
    ...
);
```

In your example the compare function compares the 'note' array with the 'year' and the 'type' arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort), and not `uasort`

Your approach would work, if the input was in the form that [Ronald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118361/620813) mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using uasort? because I would like to use my own function.